# FInding a better method for determining y intercept in r after weibull fit

Tags: r, weibull-distribution

I have included a sample code of what exactly i want to get out, this is functional, but i suspect theres a much better method of determining when my curve crosses the y threshold, any help would be much appreciated.

```
library("MASS")
suppressMessages(library("drc"))

Konc <- c(0.42, 0.30, 0.24, 0.21, 0.18, 0.15, 0.12, 0.09, 0.06, 0.00)
Response <- c(0.231, 0.299, 0.520, 0.720, 0.874, 0.917, 0.950, 0.953, 0.960, 0.965)
Response.df = data.frame(Response,Konc)  

plot(Konc,Response, type="o", pch=20, col="black",axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0.0,0.5),ylim=c(0,1),
xlab="Konc",ylab="Response", main="Visualization")
axis(1, pos=0)
axis(2, pos=0) 
abline(h=0.33, lty=2)

df.m1 <- drm(Response.df, fct = W2.4())
plot(df.m1, add = TRUE, type = "none", col ="black", lty=2)

summary(df.m1)

b <- df.m1$coef[1]
    c <- df.m1$coef[2]
d <- df.m1$coef[3]
    e <- df.m1$coef[4]
Weibull <- function(x){ c + (d-c) * (1 - exp(- exp(b*(log(x)-log(e)))))}
curve(Weibull,col="red", add=TRUE)

Intersection <- optimize(function(x) abs(0.33-Weibull(x)), c(.0,.50))$minimum
Intersection
abline(v=Intersection, lty=2, col="red")
```

Another solution than the one Roland provided

```
Intersection <- 0.33
g <- function(x) Intersection - Weibull(x)
uniroot(g,c(0,1))$root
[1] 0.2929989
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pencil and paper is your friend for this:

```
y0 <- 0.33
x0 <- unname(e*(-log(1-(y0-c)/(d-c)))^(1/b))
#[1] 0.2929993

Weibull(x0)
#c:(Intercept) 
#         0.33
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for, i found another solution as well ill edit into the question.

Comment: Your solutions are all numeric optimization, i.e., less efficient and of course only correct within a tolerance.

Comment: Yeah your right, and i will be using your solution, i just thought id include mine incase someone needed a quick and dirty solution without taking the time to solving for y